# how to change image according to data in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android and I am developing an application that has to change image according to data sent from another screen in android. 
How can this be achieved?
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: have you tried something. please post your code.

Comment: do you want to pass data from one activity to another? if so, look at this question to see how to pass the data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from one activity to another by using extras.

On you first activity call something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_ID", id_you_want_to_send);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in the other activity you can read this data by doing the following:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = -1;
if (extras != null) {
    id = extras.getInt("SOME_ID");
}
```

then you can set the image inside and if-else or a switch-case of your choosing and to change the image inside the image view you need the following code:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findById(your_image_id);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.the_image_you_want_to_set);
```

where the `image_you_want_to_set` is inside the drawable folder of your project.

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: thank you marimaf the image change code which you have mentioned solved my problem